# Data binding image to Panorama Control in WP7 not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

Can anyone shed some light as to why the following code is not working?  By "not working" I mean the image is not rendered in the Panorama control:

**XAML**

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="My Control">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RandomImage}"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>
```

**C#**

```
public string RandomImage { get; set; }
```

**Note:**  The RandomImage property is set to a public jpg image on the internet.

**EDIT**

I have also tried to change the RandomImage property to ImageSource but did not have any luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna hazard a guess that you're setting `RandomImage` at some point after the page loads, which means that the binding has already been checked.  You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call your `PropertyChanged` event in the setter for `RandomImage`.  For a detailed explanation of this, check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

The long and short of it is that the binding is checked when the page loads and then not again unless something triggers it.  Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` means that when you call your `PropertyChanged` event, it notifies the UI to check the binding again and see what's new so it can update itself.

Comment: I am setting the property before the call to InitializeComponent() in the Page Load event.  This is actually simplified code from that which I had in a view model which implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ok - I just threw out the most obvious thing I came up with based on your code.  I wonder though if this blog article might be of use to you: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-imagebrush-binding-problem-workaround

Comment: Your link provided a workaround.  It doesn't look like the ImageSource property on an ImageBrush participates in data binding.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Right, I read the post that's why I gave you the link - there's no way to bind to it, so I figured perhaps the workaround would be useful to you.